# Translating parts of sentences based on its context

Tags: machine-translation

I am working on an application that needs to be able to translate parts of sentences. The problem is that if I send the parts to a translation API like Google Translate, the translations often don't make sense in the context they occurred in. Example:

> He **leaves** the building

If I translate **leaves** to any destination language I will probably get a result in the context of "leaves of a tree", which of course makes no sense in the example. So, translation needs to keep context into account. If I expand the translation sentence to **He leaves** I get the correct translation of **He leaves**. However, I lose the translation of **leaves**, which is the word I am looking for.

Does anyone have any idea as to how I should approach this? Keep in mind  the Google Translate API is a paid API, so I would like to minimize the amount of translations I request from the API.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are right that translating words without sentence context is hopeless.

(Whereas translating sentences without paragraph context can work most of the time, for many content types.)

Luckily, the Google Translate API, like the Chrome integration, and most machine translation APIs, is smart about HTML tags (the default parameters include `format=html`).

So one good option is to **wrap the word or phrase in which you are interested in HTML tags**.

You can try this in the console:

[image]

It should be easy to **parse the contents of the HTML tag back out**, then you can lemmatise.

*Note 1*:
The consumer-facing standalone Google Translate UI does not expose this option, to try it you must translate via the API console or programmatically, or translate pages with Chrome.

*Note 2*:
There are some nuances because the words in translations are inherently not 1:1.  Sometimes the word becomes two words, and occasionally the word has a null representation in the target language.

1:2 example:
en: `He <span>left</span> the building.`
it: `Ha <span>lasciato</span> l'edificio.`
[Arguably the *ha* should also be included.]

1:0 example:
en: `How <span>are</span> you?`
ru: `Как вы?`
[*to be* is usually dropped in Russian.]
en: `How are <span>you</span>?`
it: `Come stai?`
[Pronouns are often dropped in Italian.]

2:1 example:
en: `He is always <span>screwing</span> things up.`
it: `Sempre <span>spiegazza</span> le cose.`
[English and other languages have [separable verbs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separable_verb).  The actual input here is *to screw up*, not *to screw*.]

For you this is some work but it is also in fact very useful information, and anyway it is easier for you to process *lasciato* to get the correct lemma *lasciare*.

See [cloud.google.com/translate/docs/reference/rest](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/reference/rest) for more parameter documentation

Comment: It's been a while, but thanks for this. I, in collaboration with my supervisor, have written a simple Python implementation of this: https://github.com/mircealungu/python-translators

Comment: My pleasure, looks useful, congratulations on shipping some code.

Comment: Thx so much for this answer! Not even Chat GPT was able to come up with a solution for this and I've been probing it with questions for like half an hour or so

Comment: Just a matter of time before they crawl this answer.  One day someone will look back at us like we look at the Akkadians writing on clay tablets.

Answer (score 1):

My idea:

Send "He leaves", and to understand which part is "he" and which part is "leaves", intersect with all possible translations of "leaves" (keep locally a bilingual dictionary of all possible translations of all words in all forms)

Comment: That sounds like a very solid solution for single words, but what about phrases? Two or three words is often still not enough context for translation. Thank you for your contribution though, I think it would work great for single word translation. I will be trying this to test its effectiveness.

Comment: You send the whole sentence, match the translation against possible translations of each word in the sentence, and find the location of the word or phrase you want to translate.

Comment: The weak part, imho, is where do you find or how do you create a dictionary which includes all words in all forms (including all forms of their translation).  For instance, there are 4 cases in German, and some languages have even more cases. You cannot just translate dog as hund, as it can be hundes, hund, hunde, or hunden

Comment: Interesting. I think there are still a few issues, but I will try it out. Regarding the issue you were talking about : the Glosbe API is a free word to word translation service. You give it a word and it gives back a list of possible translations. It doesn't seem to show all 4 German forms of "dog", but initially it only needs to work for Dutch to English anyways and I don't think it is as much of a problem in Dutch. Also, I recognise that a perfect solution probably does not exist, so any improvement on the current implementation  is great. Thanks :)

Comment: Warning: this is non-trivial to implement.

Answer (score 0):

I have applied the suggestions I found above, but still in my case I have some troubles. I am translating medicine active ingredients from Italian to Enlgish. The corious thing is that

- the google search page translator translates it correclty
- the API not

The active ingredient to be translated is "Testosterone Enantato", i have enricehd the sentence with "Il principio attivo della medicina è Testosterone Enantato". Here what i get

1. google research web page: "The active ingredient of the medicine is Testosterone Enanthate" --> "Testosterone Enanthate" that is correct.
2. google Translate API: "Testosterone Enantato", it leaves it in Italian

Any idea?

here the screnshot of the google web page with correct translation

[image]