# Find phrase/word equivalent in translated sentence

Tags: android, algorithm, kotlin, translation, machine-translation

As in question - I'm wondering if there is a way to find word/phrase equivalent when I have two translated sentences. For example:

> - No. - Me **molesta**.
> - No. - But it **bothers** me.

Is there an algorithm that would tell me **molesta** in Spanish is **bothers** in English? I have more sentences like that and I would like to get list of possible translations of word **molesta** for example. I know it is very general question but I don't know where I should search solution. I would do it in Kotlin. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you currently using any type of translation service?

Comment: Syntax in different languages might be very different also one word can become multiple during translation. I know there is a project trying something similar by analizing the official paper of the EU-parlament (They want to train a automated translator).

Comment: Why not simply download the dict.cc database and use it as lookup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few libraries for **word alignment**:

- [**eflomal**](https://github.com/robertostling/eflomal)
- [**fast align**](https://github.com/clab/fast_align)
- [**Awesome**](https://www.reddit.com/r/machinetranslation/comments/l39pip/awesome_a_new_bertbased_alignment_lib_from_g/)

If you are anyway starting from the original text only and using machine translation, you can use the [`includeAlignment`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/translator/word-alignment) option of the Microsoft Translator API or wrap each word in HTML tags, as described [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41178854/4486860).  All major machine translation APIs support HTML translation.  However, we at ModelFront have noticed that including HTML tags can hurt the translation quality.

You could also look at libraries for **term extraction**:

- [TM2TB](https://github.com/luismond/tm2tb)